# RStudio Desktop integration with linux server

Tags: linux, r, rstudio

I am trying to integrate **RStudio** Desktop which is  installed in my local machine to **R** which is installed on Linux server. Is, there any way to achieve this?

I know I can use RStudio Server directly, but my department people don't want to install one more webserver on the Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly what type of "integration" are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: It is not possible: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200742083-Local-RStudio-and-remote-R-session - see also https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200663856-Remote-session