# Can RStudio Desktop be used as a client to RStudio Server? (instead of the web interface)

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am aware that I can use RStudio server on my remote machine, and connect to that via a web browser on my client machine.

However, I would prefer not to use my web browser. Is it possible to set up RStudio Desktop to connect to the RStudio Server?

Many thanks

Comment: [No.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200742083-Local-RStudio-and-remote-R-session)

Comment: Also [No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735669/rstudio-desktop-integration-with-linux-server) (prev SO q w/o an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative: create Rstudio Server [webapp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher).

This is how I did it:

1. Login to the rstudio server from the browser using serverip:8787
2. On the menu bar, go to File (or Tools in some cases) -> Create application shortcut. This dialogue box will appear:
   [Rstudio shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1SNX.png)
3. Add it to your desktop by selecting and run it as if you're running rstudio desktop version.
   [Rstudio webapp screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyiv9.png)